# Prove $(\cos{x})^\prime = -\sin{x}$ and $\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus

We define the functions $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ as follows:

$ \sin{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}$

$ \cos{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}}$

Using this fact show that:

(i) $(\cos{x})^\prime = -\sin{x}$

(ii) $\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1$

I've seen proofs on these using other methods but not sure how to arrive at the same conclusion using the definition of the functions stated above.

I managed to proof $(\sin{x})^\prime = \cos{x}$ by:

$ \sin{x}^\prime = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}$  = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}}$ = $\cos{x}$

But when I tried to differentiate $\cos{x}$, I got stuck here:

$ \cos{x}^\prime = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}}$, which is not exactly $-\sin{x}$

Comment: Can you differentiate the series representation of $\cos x$?\

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335284/finding-the-derivatives-of-sinx-and-cosx?rq=1 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728241/sin2x-cos2x-1-using-power-series?rq=1

Comment: Do you know the identities $(x^n)'=n x^{n-1}$, $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ and $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$?

Comment: Differentiating $\cos x$ observe that $(1)'=0$. This means you have no $x^{-1}$ term in the series.

Comment: Your mistake is in dividing by zero. $0/0!$ is **not** $1/(-1)!$.